# Javascript blur function not working consistently

Tags: javascript

In this example we use math functions to create a blurred copy of an image. The way we will blur the image is by scrambling pixels that are near each other.

We begin by creating a blank image and writing the loop to let us color each pixel in the image. For each pixel we will do one of two things: half the time, we will simply copy the pixel from the old picture into the new picture without changing anything. The other half of the time we will find a pixel nearby and copy that one instead.

Now we must figure out how to find a "nearby" pixel. We will define some value for how far away the new pixel will be (we used 10 pixels) and then we write a function that will give a (x,y) point that is a random amount between 0 and 10 pixels away in each direction. Before we use the new (x,y) point, we must check to be sure it is still a valid pixel position in the image. For example, we may be at a pixel that is on the very top of the image. Our random point generator tells us to go up by 3 pixels, but since we are on the top of the image (y = 0) we cannot very well go up by three pixels (y would be -3)! If the random number is too big (larger than the dimension -1) or too small (less than 0) then we will just use the closest number that is valid.

Once we have a valid pixel that is some amount away we use its red, green, and blue values as the new pixel's values.

```js
function nearby(image, x, y) {
  var newX = x + Math.random() * 10 - 5;
  if (newX > image1.getWidth()) {
    newX = newX - 5;
  }
  if (newX < 0) {
    newX = newX + 5;
  } else {
    newX = newX;
  }
  var newY = y + Math.random() * 10 - 5;
  if (newY > image1.getHeight()) {
    newY = newY - 5;
  }
  if (newY < 0) {
    newY = newY + 5;
  } else {
    newY = newY;
  }
  return image.getPixel(newX, newY);
}

function blur(image) {
  for (var pixel of image.values()) {
    x = pixel.getX();
    y = pixel.getY();
    var orgPixel = image.getPixel(x, y);
    if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
      var other = nearby(image, x, y);
      output.setPixel(x, y, other);
    } else {
      output.setPixel(x, y, orgPixel);
    }
  }
  return output;
}
var image1 = new SimpleImage("duvall.jpg");
var output = new SimpleImage(image1.getWidth(), image1.getHeight());
blur(image1);
print(output);
```

----i used one of the pictures in my file but any picture should do.

Comment: Start by properly formatting your code, please. It's impossible to see at a glance what the logic flow is supposed to be without indentations! (Often, this also makes errors visible that went unnoticed before.)

Comment: You are using `image1` inside `nearby` but you wanted to use `image`

Comment: some error i get:Cannot read properties of null (reading 'data')

Comment: sorry I tried my best to format my code. I think I wasn't taught in the best way to write code, so that's what I got. I will try again. I was very frustrated with this assignment since i was stuck here for a week.

Comment: Is this an assignment for school, or something you found on the internet to practice? We're missing the `SimpleImage` external library as well.

Comment: Yes can use this for SimpleImage   <script src="http://www.dukelearntoprogram.com/course1/common/js/image/SimpleImage.js">
    </script>

Comment: I don't know why but it worked now after I did some indentation, but it's weird and I couldn't figure out why..But thank you everyone!